# Posting Unicode data from HTML form

Tags: java, spring, utf-8, character-encoding

When I post UTF-8 Unicode characters from html form, for example, in french,
département becomes dÃ©partement. I have set `<meta />` in html pages,
I also added spring CharacterSetEncodingFilter. But on controller, I recieve
dÃ©partement. How to get back the original text that was posted ?

Encoding Filter -

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Could you please share the encoding filter code?

Comment: The configuration for the encoding filter looks good. Therefore, this could also be a problem with the encoding used by your java files. If you are using `maven` then build your project with the following property - `<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>`